# How does driver firmware get copied onto an Android device?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, firmware, android-firmware

**Prerequisite/Background Info:**  After looking in the Android source code file listed below:

```
/system/core/init/firmware_handler.cpp
```

I can see a list of locations that the kernel can retrieve firmware files from, for example:

```
/etc/firmware/
/vendor/firmware/
/firmware/image/
```

**Problem Statement:**  Since Android dynamically creates these directories after it boots up for the first time, when the file system initializes, there is no way to simply copy the firmware file into one of these directories before building the source code and generate a boot image that contains the firmware file.  I would like the firmware file to be automatically copied onto the device when it is flashed with the boot image, instead of waiting for the device to boot up and then manually copying the firmware file onto the device.

**Additional Info:**  While researching this issue, I read that a script which runs in user-space copies firmware files into the appropriate directory after Android boots up.  However, I was unable to find such a script.

Is there a script that runs after Android boots up to copy firmware files into one of these dirctories?  Or is there some config file that I need to add the firmware file to so that it will be copied into the boot image?

Comment: the system image you are using is a prebuilt one or you are making it yourself ?

Comment: I'm making it myself.

Comment: if you are making it yourself then you can include these firmware files while building system image

Comment: Thank you!  Do you know how to do this?  Is it accomplished through the `initramfs`?

Comment: No. I am assuming that you are making your own system image with some build tool like open embedded or yokto etc, in those systems you can add your files in the recipe of system image.

Comment: Hmm... at least Android x86 contains a number of firmwares and I believe they are part of the image.